# Scaling solution of the diffusion equation

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I am studying the book "A guide to first-passage processes", by Sidney Redner, and at page 14 he derives a solution of the diffusion equation

$\dfrac{\partial c(x,t)}{\partial t} = D \dfrac{\partial^2c(x,t)}{\partial x^2} \,,$

based on a scaling ansatz of the form

$c(x,t) = \dfrac{1}{X(t)} f[x/X(t)]  \,.$

The book says: "substituting this ansatz into the diffusion equation gives

$X(t) \dot{X}(t) = -D \dfrac{f''(u)}{f(u) + uf'(u)} \,,$ $\quad$ where $u=\dfrac{x}{X(t)}$."

The prime denotes differentiation w.r.t. $u$ and the overdot denotes the time derivative. Can anybody please give me a hand on how to arrive there?

**EDIT**: As pointed out in the comments and in the answers, this is simply repeated applications of the chain rule. What is important to keep in mind is that

$\dfrac{\partial f(u)}{\partial t} = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} = f'\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}\,,$

$\dfrac{\partial f(u)}{\partial x} = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial 
u}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}= f'\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\,,$

and then everything works out smoothly. Thank you everybody.

Comment: You should edit your post to include _how_ you managed to 'arrive at the following formula'. Just note that this is just repeated applications of the chain rule. If you apply the chain rule correctly, the result falls out immediately. Computing $$c_{t} = - \frac{\dot{X}}{X^{2}} f + \frac{1}{X} \cdot \left( - \frac{x \dot{X}}{X^{2}} \right) f', \quad c_{x} = \frac{1}{X^{2}} f', \quad c_{xx} = \frac{1}{X^{3}} f''$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$c(x,t) = \dfrac{1}{X(t)} f[x/X(t)]  \,.$$
Differentiate twice wrt $x$:
$$\dfrac {dc(x,t)}{dx} = \dfrac{1}{X^2(t)} f_u[u]  \,.$$
$$\dfrac {d^2c(x,t)}{dx^2} = \dfrac{1}{X^3(t)} f_{uu}[u]  \,.$$
Differentiate wrt $t$:
$$\dfrac {dc(x,t)}{dt} = \dfrac{1}{X^2(t)} \left ( -f_u[u] \dfrac {xX_t(t)} {X(t)}- X_t(t)f[u] \right )$$
$$\dfrac {dc(x,t)}{dt} = \left ( -f_u[u] \dfrac {xX_t(t)} {X^3(t)}- \dfrac{X_t(t)f[u] }{X^2(t)} \right )$$

The diffusion equation is:
$$\dfrac{\partial c(x,t)}{\partial t} = D \dfrac{\partial^2c(x,t)}{\partial x^2} \,,$$
$$f_u[u] \dfrac {xX_t(t)} {X^3(t)}+ \dfrac{X_t(t)f[u] }{X^2(t)} =-\dfrac{D}{X^3(t)} f_{uu}[u]  \,.$$
$$f_u[u]  {xX_t(t)} + {X_t(t)f[u] }{X(t)} =-{D}f_{uu}[u]  \,.$$
The result follows:
$$X_t(t){X(t)}\left (f_u[u] u + f[u]  \right )=-{D}f_{uu}[u]  $$
$$ \boxed {X_t(t){X(t)}=-{D} \dfrac  {f_{uu}[u] }{\left (f_u[u] u + f[u] \right )}}$$I think that the derivative at the denominator is taken according to the variable $u$.  At the numerator too, its taken with respect to u. Where:
$$u=\frac x {X(t)}$$